# How to create iphone toolbar - dropdown/expanded menu

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

What's the best way to create "Expanded toolbar menus"?

Example:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's just a subview.  You could create it in IB and position it so that it's over the button that was used to bring it up.  I would probably add it to the main view in IB but make it initially "hidden" so that when the trigger button is touched, all you have to do is unhide the view.  Or you could load it from its own NIB.

Answer (score 0):

I've find out that it's called popover -UIPopoverController - available only on iPad, so I have to create it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Luke, I use this on my applications, it's very similar to UIPopoverController and you can use on the iPhone.

https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover