# iPhone tableview drop-down menu

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller with a table view in it and several buttons.  I would like to add an additional tableview on top of the view like this (or at least what it would look like if anybody wanted to be my friend :-)):

[image: TableViewPopdown]

I don't want to just add this as a subview (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060681/uitextfield-with-a-dropdown-menu-for-iphone) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714138/how-to-create-iphone-toolbar-dropdown-expanded-menu))enter link description here since I don't want to check which table view is being used in my tableview delegate and datasource methods.  I would rather use a separate view controller.

I don't want to use a picker because I need to display a bit of info with the items in the list.

I have no problem creating the view with the corresponding controller, but how do I add it on top of the current view, just hiding portions of it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why dont you want to add it as a subview?

Comment: I believe that's a UIPopoverController. You can add a tableview as a subview of the popover if you want.

Comment: UIPopoverController is only available on iPad

Comment: I didn't want to add it as a subview because then the tableview's datasource and delegate methods are being implemented in the parent view controller, which is already implementing those methods for a separate tableview.

Comment: You can have 2 UITableViews in one parent view controller.  In each data source and delegate method, just use `if (tableView == mainTableView) {} else if (tableView == popoverTableView) {}` to determine what to load in each.

Comment: Sure, I was just trying to compartmentalize the code to make it cleaner.

Comment: I ended up adding the subview and using the if else statements in the tableview delegate and data source methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I simply added logic in my tableview datasource and delegate methods to destingwish between the two tableviews (as suggested by Scott Bossak above.  But I have since switched to building my two views in storyboard and adding their view controllers as usual.  However, to present the second table view I instanciate it like so:

```
SecondTableViewContriller *secondTVC = [self.storyboard instanciateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondTVC"];
```

then  add it as a child view controller:

```
[self addChildViewController: secondVC];
[secondVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I then implemented a protocol to pass the information back to the parent view controller once a row has been selected.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has a sample code of TableView which deals with this issue. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010139
Above URL is the link to download the sample code from Apple developer library.
Hope it helps.

Comment: While thats pretty cool, it was not quite what I was hoping for.  I've posted my final solution below.

Answer (score 0):

This might be overly simplistic for your application, but I have found it to be effective when I have had to do something similar.

You can add this 'drop down menu' view controller's view to the main UIWindow of the entire application.  You can add a UIGestureRecognizer on the window as well.  If the tap is outside of the view, make it fade away and remove it from the view hierarchy.